# Can't run Contoso Javascript on Local Machine

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I tried to run the Contoso project on my Visual Studio Express 2012 RC for Windows 8, it reports this error. How to fix it?

```
Exception was thrown but not handled in user code at line 183, column 5 in Function code

0x80070002 - JavaScript runtime error: The system cannot find the file specified.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the Contoso Cookbook reference application for Windows 8 (available from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29854))?  If so, you should be using [Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8](http://aka.ms/JenVS2012) and not Visual Studio 2008.  You will also need the Windows 8 operating system to run this.

Comment: Yah, I'm using Visual Studio 2012 RC for Windows 8.

Comment: Are you using the Release Preview version of Windows 8 with VS 2012 RC?  If you upgrade to the RTM version of Windows 8, you should also install the RTM version of Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: If you don't have a version mismatch, can you go to line 183, column 5 and see what file it can't find?  Also, are you running the HTML or XAML version of the Contoso Cookbook?  I've seen some people have issues using the XAML version, which can be resolved by downloading Callisto from http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0526563b-7a48-4b17-a087-a35cea701052 and/or fixing the reference to it.